# removeAttr("style") and attr("style","") not working

Tags: jquery, attr

http://synergine.net/rain.php

hello. I am trying, unsuccessfully, to clear the style attribute for all elements in .ripple divs:

```
function contact(level){
focus_ripple = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
$("#"+level+" .ripple"+focus_ripple+" p").css("opacity",1);
$("#"+level+" .ripple"+focus_ripple+" .fourth").animate({
    height: "324px",
    width: "324px",
    top: "-162px",
    left: "-162px",
    "border-radius": "162px"
},{duration: 1000, queue: false});
$("#"+level+" .ripple"+focus_ripple+" .third").animate({
    height: "108px",
    width: "108px",
    top: "-54px",
    left: "-54px",
    "border-radius": "54px"
},{duration: 1000, queue: false});
$("#"+level+" .ripple"+focus_ripple+" .second").animate({
    height: "32px",
    width: "32px",
    top: "-18px",
    left: "-18px",
    "border-radius": "18px"
},{duration: 1000, queue: false});
$("#"+level+" .ripple"+focus_ripple+" .first").animate({
    height: "10px",
    width: "10px",
    top: "-6px",
    left: "-6px",
    "border-radius": "6px"
},{duration: 1000, queue: false});
$("#"+level+" .ripple"+focus_ripple+" p").animate({
    opacity: 0
},{duration: 1550, queue: false});
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#"+level+" .ripple"+focus_ripple+" p").removeAttr("style");
},1575);
counter++;
```

}

Any help with this is greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: it was a known bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9699 - what version of jQuery and browser are you using?

Comment: I've also tried setting the style in the settimeout function. nothing is working after the animation to opacity: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) works for me on 1.7.2:

```
$("div").click(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr("style");
})​
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adrianonantua/p5Dcs/

You have to make sure your selector actually bring results.

Comment: absolutely. removeAttr normally works for me too. just can't figure out what the stumbling block is toward the end of the code that I posted (nothing is working after animation to opacity:0).